# ef core ftp file upload cqrs

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ftp

I want to upload FTP file but I am using Ef Core and CQRS structure. I don't know how to operate on CreateHandler.

File Upload;
using System.Net;

```
namespace Medoper.Application.Helpers
 {
     public class FileUpload
    {
       private void UploadFtp(string FileName, string FilePath)
        {
           using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
              client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("cdnname", "cdnpassword");
                 client.UploadFile("cdnaddress" + "/asd/" + FileName, 
         WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, FilePath);
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

CreateHandler

```
   public class SliderCreateHandler : IRequestHandler<SliderCreate, 
   ApiResponse<SliderResponse>>
    {
     private readonly IUnitOfWork _repo;
     private readonly IMapper _mapper;


public SliderCreateHandler(IUnitOfWork repo, IMapper mapper)
{
    _repo = repo;
    _mapper = mapper;
}

public async Task<ApiResponse<SliderResponse>> Handle(SliderCreate request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var mapped = _mapper.Map<Slider>(request);

    if (mapped == null)
        return new ErrorApiResponse<SliderResponse>(ResultMessage.NotCreatedBlog);

    var model = await _repo.Sliders.AddAsync(mapped);
    var response = _mapper.Map<SliderResponse>(model);

    return new SuccessApiResponse<SliderResponse>(response);
}
```

}

I'm testing the create process over swagger and the image;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIWG8.png)

Where I'm stuck is CreateHandler.

Comment: What's the question?  EF Core is an ORM, it has nothing to do with FTP. You didn't post any EF Core code. What you posted looks like the "generic repo" **anti**pattern. `UploadFtp` is using the obsolete `WebClient` class that is nothing more than a legacy wrapper over HttpClient in .NET Core. It's definitely *not* a good FTP Client. It doesn't call `SliderCreateHandler` so it's unclear what the problem is (apart from that "repository"). Finally, there's no CQRS either. No commands, no queries. Just two classes that don't seem to be related

Comment: How do I call and use the FileUpload class I wrote in CreateHandler?

Comment: You should read [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). A DbContext is already a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, a DbSet is already a Repository. As for `How do I call and use the FileUpload class I wrote in CreateHandler?` what does that mean? Why did you create classes if you don't know what they're for? What's the job of that `SliderCreateHandler` in the first place and why does it need to use FTP at all? In fact, what's the point of that `SliderCreateHandler`? It doesn't read or write anything.

Comment: And unless you use HiLo for IDs, that `AddAsync` isn't doing anything either

Comment: Don't rush to use every pattern you see in a course. Patterns are meant to solve specific problems, in specific conditions. Don't use them until you actually have those problems. *DON'T* go looking for justifications to use patterns. The very fact your code is so convoluted and yet doesn't even start solving your real problem is a clear sign the design is wrong. Start by writing *simple* code that solves your business problem, and add extra code only if you encounter an actual problem that needs solving